# android convert hex to character

Tags: java, android, hex

I want to know how to convert "\u106A" to "A" or something else? I've found following coding to convert Hex to character but it failed

```
public static String convertHexToString(String hex){         
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();

  for( int i=0; i<hex.length()-1; i+=2 ){
      String output = hex.substring(i, (i + 2));
      int decimal = Integer.parseInt(output, 16);
      sb.append((char)decimal);
      temp.append(decimal);
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava%28java.lang.String%29) available in [`Commons Lang`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//download_lang.cgi) Apache library.

```
final String input = "\\u0048\\u0065\\u006c\\u006c\\u006f\\u002c\\u0020\\u0057\\u006f\\u0072\\u006c\\u0064\\u0021";
final String output = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(input);

System.out.println("Output : " + output);
// Output : Hello, World!
```